# How to increment variable value in Until activity until variable get value 100 in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have "Until" activity in Data Factory.
It is running until it get value

```
@equals(variables('until_flag'), true)
```

I have created new variable "loop_count".
I would like add to Until activity new feature where activity is stopped after it has run 100 times.  So basically I need to add +1 to loop_count until loop_count get value 100.
If loop_count get value 100 then until_flag must be set to true.

I would need advice

1. How to add +1 to variable "loop_count"
2. How to change until_flag value to true of loop_count is 100?

Answer (score 0):

Using `set variable` activity increment the loop count and update the **unti_flag** to true. In my repro as an example, I am only checking if the loop_count is 2. Therefore `until` activity loops only 2 times.

1. Create 3 variables **loop_count**, **until_flag** with default value as false and **previous_loop** with default value as 0.

[image]

2. In `Until` activity settings, add your until condition to check if the until_flag is **true**.

`@equals(variables('until_flag'),'true')`

[image]

3. Inside `Until activity`, add 3 set variable activities,

   (i) **Set variable activity1**: To increment the loop_count variable by 1.

   `@string(add(int(variables('previous_count')),1))`

[image]

(ii) **Set variable activity2**: Assign loop_count variable value to previous_count.

`@variables('loop_count')`

[image]

(iii) **Set variable activity3**: check the loop_count variable value and if the value equals to the required value (ex:100), then update until_flag to true.

`@if(equals(variables('loop_count'),'2'),'true','false')`

[image]

4. Output

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can also check the loop count directly in Until activity condition to stop the loop instead of checking the flag by updating it.